# Remove background from VectorPlot

Tags: plotting, regions

when I plot this `VectorPlot` with a `RegionFunction`

```
VectorPlot[{1, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, RegionFunction ->Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1], VectorMarkers -> "Segment"]
```

we get

[image]

Now I wanted to remove the blue boundary and the background but using the options `BoundaryStyle -> None` and  `Background -> None` doesn't change anything? Am I using the wrong options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`RegionBoundaryStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionBoundaryStyle.html) and [`RegionFillingStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFillingStyle.html).

```
VectorPlot[{1, Sqrt[1 - x^2 - y^2]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 VectorMarkers -> "Segment", 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 <= 1], 
 RegionBoundaryStyle -> None, RegionFillingStyle -> None]
```

[image: VectorPlot]